# Withdrawing method for a class in python

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm doing some homework dealing with classes in Python. But I'm stuck on one part I don't quite understand.

It tells me to:

--> write a method named `withdraw()` that withdraws the specified amount specified from the account. The balance in the account is reduced by the amount specified in the parameter of the method. The balance should only be reduced if the amount specified in the parameter less than or equal to balance

This is my program

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self,id=0):
        self.__id = id
        self.__balance = 0
        self.__annualInterestRate = 0

    def getid(self):
        return self.__id

    def getbalance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def getannualInterestRate(self):
        return self.__getannualInterestRate

    def setid(self):
        self.__id = id

    def setbalance(self):
        self.__balance = balance

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate/12


    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.__balance * getMonthlyInterestRate()
```

Then I will have to:

```
def withdraw():
   # I don't know what to do here
```

Comment: `getMonthlyInterestRate` and `getMonthlyInterest` are missing the `self` parameter

Comment: For the `getMonthlyInterestRate`and `getMonthlyInterest` it says to write a a method named getMonthlyInterest() that return the monthly interest amount. The monthly interest amount can be calculated by using balance * monthly interest rate. The monthly interest rate can be computed by dividing the annual interest rate by 12.

Comment: Use `self.__balance * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()` instead of `self.__balance * getMonthlyInterestRate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various errors in your code. I modify `class A` to a executable class including `withdraw` function

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self,id=0):
        self.__id = id
        self.__balance = 0
        self.__annualInterestRate = 0

    def getid(self):
        return self.__id

    def getbalance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def getannualInterestRate(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate

    def setid(self,id):
        self.__id = id

    def setbalance(self, balance):
        self.__balance = balance

    def setannualInterestRate(self, rate):
        self.__annualInterestRate = rate

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate/12

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.__balance * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount <= self.__balance:
            self.__balance -= amount
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the implied `self` argument (here and in a few more methods) and an `amount`:

```
def withdraw(self, amount):
   # subtract amount from self.__balance
```

You also should read up on `return` statements as well before moving on to classes.